Assembly Calculator not getting inputs and working through program
I've been working on this calculator is Assembly, and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. It out put's the first string but I don't think it's getting my inputs after that.
I'll attach the code so you can check it out.
.ORIG x3000
; Strings used in the program

num_temp2      .FILL     #0
num_temp      .FILL     #0

; Program starts here


inputFirstNum  .STRINGZ "Input the first number you would like to use: "

ContProgram
    JSR ClearReg
    
    LEA R0, inputFirstNum
    PUTS
    JSR GetInput
    LD R1, num_temp

    
    LEA R0, inputOpp
    PUTS
    GETC
    ST R0, num_temp
    LD R0, num_temp
    JSR DecodeOperation
    
    LEA R0, inputSecNum
    PUTS
    JSR GetInput
    LD R2, num_temp



; Definitions for operation codes
codesArray    .FILL     #-43  ; '+'
              .FILL     #-45  ; '-'
              .FILL     #-42  ; '*'
              .FILL     #-47  ; '/'


GetInput
    AND R3, R3, #0        ; Clear R3 for digit count
    AND R4, R4, #0        ; Clear R4 for accumulated number
InputLoop
    GETC                  ; Read character into R0
    OUT                   ; Echo character
    ADD R5, R0, R6        ; Subtract 48 by adding R6 (which contains -48)
    BRn InputDone         ; Break loop if input is not a digit
    ; Perform R4 = R4 * 10 + R5 using repeated addition
    AND R6, R6, #0        ; Clear R6 to use as temporary register for sum
    LD R7, ten            ; Load the constant 10 into R7
    ADD R2, R4, #0        ; Copy R4 to R2 for repeated addition
MultiplyByTen
    ADD R6, R6, R2        ; Accumulate R4 into R6, 10 times
    ADD R7, R7, #-1       ; Decrement the counter
    BRp MultiplyByTen     ; Repeat until counter is zero
    ADD R4, R6, R5        ; Add the new digit to the accumulated result in R6
    ADD R3, R3, #1        ; Increment digit count
    BR InputLoop
InputDone
    ST R4, num_temp2       ; Store the number
    RET
    
    
ADDITION
    ADD R4, R1, R2
    BR OPERATION_FINISHED
    
SUBTRACTION
    NOT R2, R2
    ADD R2, R2, #1
    ADD R4, R1, R2
    BR OPERATION_FINISHED
    
MULTIPLY
    AND R3, R3, #0
    AND R4, R2 #0
MULTIPLY_LOOP
    BRz DONE_MULTIPLY
    ADD R3, R3, R1
    ADD R4, R4, #-1
    BRnp MULTIPLY_LOOP
DONE_MULTIPLY
    BRnzp OPERATION_FINISHED

DIVIDE
    AND R3, R3, #0
    AND R4, R1, #0
DIVIDE_LOOP
    NOT R5, R2
    ADD R5, R5, #1
    ADD R6, R4, R5
    BRn DIVIDE_DONE
    ADD R4, R4, R5
    ADD R3, R3, #1
    BRnzp DIVIDE_LOOP
DIVIDE_DONE
    BRnzp OPERATION_FINISHED


DecodeOperation
    LD R3, codesArray     ; Load base address of codesArray
    ADD R4, R0, #0        ; Copy operation character to R4
DecodeLoop
    LDR R5, R3, #0        ; Load operation code
    NOT R6, R5            ; Invert code for comparison
    ADD R6, R6, R4        ; Add inverted code to character
    BRz ExecuteOperation  ; Branch if zero (match)
    ADD R3, R3, #1        ; Move to next code
    BRnzp DecodeLoop      ; Continue if not out of codes
    RET


ExecuteOperation
    AND R3, R3, #0        ; Clear R3 for safe operation execution
    ADD R3, R5, #0        ; Copy operation code to R3 for checking
    BRz ADDITION          ; Branch if R3 is 0 (addition)
    BRp MULTIPLY_CHECK    ; Check further if it's multiplication or division
    BRn SUBTRACTION       ; Branch if R3 is negative (subtraction)

MULTIPLY_CHECK
    ADD R3, R3, #-2       ; Adjust R3 to check for multiplication or division
    BRz MULTIPLY
    BRp DIVIDE


    
STOP_PROGRAM
    TRAP x25

resultMsg      .STRINGZ "The answer is: "

OPERATION_FINISHED
    LEA R0, resultMsg
    PUTS
    ADD R0, R4, #0        ; Assuming R4 holds the result
    OUT
    LEA R0, continue
    PUTS
    GETC
    LD R6, NEG_ONE_TEN    ; Load -110 into R6 before comparison
    ADD R0, R0, R6        ; Subtract 110 from user input to check against 'n'
    BRz STOP_PROGRAM      ; If 'n', halt the program
    BRnzp ContProgram     ; Otherwise, jump back to start if not 'n'


ClearReg
    AND R1, R1, #0
    AND R2, R2, #0
    AND R3, R3, #0    
    AND R4, R4, #0
    AND R5, R5, #0
    AND R6, R6, #0
    RET

ten .FILL #10
NEG_FORTYEIGHT .FILL #-48
NEG_ONE_TEN .FILL #-110


inputSecNum    .STRINGZ "Input the second number you would like to use: "
debugMsg1      .STRINGZ "\nDebug: First number loaded\n"
debugMsg2      .STRINGZ "\nDebug: Operation decoded\n"
inputOpp       .STRINGZ "Input operation you would like to use '+, -, *, /': "
continue       .STRINGZ "Would you like to continue? (y/n): "

.END


I've tried a ton of different ways of fixing the issue but nothing has worked so far.

Next time, write your code a few lines at a time, test them using the debugger.  Only add more code to already working code.

Debugging is an interactive activity not well suited to a Q&A forum.  Why don't you debug and tell us where it is going wrong (not doing what you want), then maybe ask a question about something specific there.

Ok thanks! I appreciate the advice, have a good one!

Do not put data in the middle of the execution path. Move your codesArray out of the way. That might or might not fix your issue but is certainly wrong.

Two errors which show up first:

In InputLoop there's
    ADD R5, R0, R6        ; Subtract 48 by adding R6 (which contains -48)
- but despite the comment R6 doesn't contain -48.
Also there the GETC and OUT traps overwrite the return address in R7; you have to save and restore it from somewhere.

